# Тест на PHP поочередно

Tags: php, html

```
<?php

$questions = [
[
     'Тас дәуірінде адам баласы орталық және шығыс Қазақстан жерін игере бастаған кезең',
    ['Мезолит','Олдувэй','Мустье','Ашель','Неолит']
],
    
 [        
     'Екі жағынан да өңделген қарапайым шапқыш тас құрал',
   [ 'Гарпун','Кетпен','Болос','Нуклеус','Бифас']
 ]
];

print_r($questions);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
 <form action="">
 <?php for($i = 0;$i < count($questions);$i++){
     echo $questions[$i][0];
     for($j = 0;$j < count($questions[$i]);$j++) {
         for($k = 0;$k < count($questions[$i]['1']);$k++) {
?><input type="radio" name="" value="">
         <?php }
     }
 } ?>
 <input type="radio" name="" value="">
 
 
 
 
 </form>  
</body>
</html>
```

Есть массив из 2 вопросов $questions[$i][0]-это вопрос $questions[$i][1][...]-это варианты, нужно вывести поочередно,я вывел вопросы но немогу вывести вариантов этих вопросов,также нужно чтобы было поочередно,если вы знаете решение я бы с радостью сидел разбирался бы в ваших кодах.

Comment: сначала 1 вопрос после ответа 2 вопрос как то так должен вывестись

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Тест на PHP из 2 вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1180316/%d0%a2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b0-php-%d0%b8%d0%b7-2-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b0)

Comment: да но там массива нету там сразу в формах написано а я не знаю как с массива на форму перевести варианты,не получается как то.

Comment: `echo $questions[$i][1][$k];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```php
<?php

$questions = [
    [
        'Тас дәуірінде адам баласы орталық және шығыс Қазақстан жерін игере бастаған кезең',
        ['Мезолит', 'Олдувэй', 'Мустье', 'Ашель', 'Неолит']
    ],
    [        
        'Екі жағынан да өңделген қарапайым шапқыш тас құрал',
        ['Гарпун', 'Кетпен', 'Болос', 'Нуклеус', 'Бифас']
    ],
];

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="">
    <?php foreach($questions as $k => $question) :?>
        <p><?= $question[0]; ?></p>
        <?php foreach($question[1] as $n => $variant) :?>
            <p><input id="variant_<?= $k; ?>_<?= $k; ?>" type="radio" name="answer[<?= $k; ?>]"><label for="variant_<?= $k; ?>_<?= $k; ?>"><?= $variant; ?></label></p>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
     <?php endforeach; ?>
     <p><buton type="submit">жалғастырыңыз</button></p>
     </form>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: большое спасибо Иван!