# Тест на php+html поочередно

Tags: php, html

```
<?php
session_start();
$questions = [
[
     'Тас дәуірінде адам баласы орталық және шығыс Қазақстан жерін игере бастаған кезең',
    ['Мезолит','Олдувэй','Мустье','Ашель','Неолит']
],
    
 [        
     'Екі жағынан да өңделген қарапайым шапқыш тас құрал',
   [ 'Гарпун','Кетпен','Болос','Нуклеус','Бифас']
 ]
];

print_r($questions);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
 <form action="proresult.php" method="POST">
 <?php for($i = 0;$i < count($questions);$i++){
     echo $questions[$i][0] . "<br>";
     for($j = 0;$j < count($questions[$i])-1;$j++) {
         for($k = 0;$k < count($questions[$i]['1']);$k++) {
?><input type="radio" name="<?=$i;?>" value="<?= $k;?>"><?php echo $questions[$i][1][$k] . "<br>";?>
         <?php }
     }
 } ?>
 <button type="submit">Жауабы</button>
 </form>  
</body>
</html>
```

Здраствуйте!Прошлый раз я не мог вывести варианты теста теперь получилось спасибо тем кто помог,теперь хочу спросить как вывести их поочередно? сначала 1 вопрос после ответа 2 вопрос?

```
<?php 
$true = 0;
$false = 0;
$true_answers = [2,4];
for($i = 0;$i < count($true_answers);$i++) {
    if($_POST[$i] == $true_answers[$i]) {
        $true++;
    }else {
        $false++;
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Дұрысы:<?php echo $true;?></p>
  <p>Қатесі:<?php echo $false;?></p>  
</body>
</html>
```

Это proresult.php

Comment: Вам уже давали ответы на этот вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1180316/Тест-на-php-из-2-вопроса Там есть пример хоть на `js` без перезагрузки страницы, хоть на `php` с перезагрузкой. Вам нужно взять один из подходов и реализовать под себя. Или уже нанять фрилансера, если не хотите разбираться в коде.

Comment: я разбирался в вашем php коде но здесь ситуация немног по другому,по крайней мере для меня,здесь тест в массиве я вывел этот массив в форму но тот код который в отправили,я не имею понятие как его использовать здесь

Comment: *Вывести их поочередно* - если вы знаете `javascript`, воспользуйтесь другим ответом, там есть пример на `js`. Если не знаете `js`, вам придется выводить ответы поочередно на `php`, с перезагрузкой страницы, проверкой, что пришло из формы и т.д. В этом случае - ситуация ровно такая же. Какая разница, в массиве вопросы или где-то еще? Проверяйте данные из формы и выводите нужный вопрос или результат, как и у меня в ответе. Если же вы не понимаете, что имеется в виду под *Проверяйте данные из формы* - тогда лучше читать учебник/мануал, это базовые вещи.

Comment: спасибо за ответ!я смотрю видеоуроки думаю получится,у меня часть кода на php можно дальше на JS писать?они будут работать вместе?

Comment: *Вместе* - не совсем верно, но в велом да, может. Лучше, конечно, сначала почитайте про `PHP + HTML + Javascript`, вам нужно общую идею понять, как и где что работает. Без этого понимания сразу писать код - плохая идея. В первую очередь - `php` выполняется на сервере и формирует некий ответ, текст страницы. И вот этот текст вида `<html>...<body>... <script>...</html>` Вы уже видите в браузере. `php` в этот момент уже никак не влияет на страницу. И вот здесь, в браузере, может работать `js` для динамического изменения этого текста.

Comment: спасибо большое!